# How to change multiple div classes with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a total noob struggling so hard to learn jquery and javascript. I think I have a very hard goal for this code and need help bad. I've spent 15+ hours trying to figure this out but still don't see the solution.

Here is my example code:

```
<div class="daddy">

  <div id="reset" onclick="changeAllFatsToSkinny">reset</div>

  <div class="skinny baby" onclick="weightChange(event)">Button01</div>
  <div class="fat baby" onclick="weightChange(event)">Button03</div>

  <div id="random" class="no class here">random text</div>

</div>
```

Goal: The click event "weightChange" changes the div class from the default "skinny baby" to "fat baby". I have the following code working…

```
function weightChange (event) {
var element = event.currentTarget;
element.className = (element.className == 'skinny baby') ? 'fat baby' : 'skinny baby';
}
```

This code may be overkill but it is working for now. The problem is that I can't figure out how to find and replace the class "fat baby" back to "skinny baby" in all the children of  the div "daddy" by clicking on the "reset" div. I got it to work somewhat but it changed the class on ALL divs including "random" divs.

I have looked at a bunch of jquery code and think I need to string together the

```
.find()
.hasClass()
.removeClass()
.addClass() or maybe just toggleClass()
```

to do all this. I think I need some kind of "if then" statement too. My problem is that I don't know enough Javascript to get the syntax right. I suck and I am very sad because of this problem. Please, ow please help me!? Thank you greatly in advance.

P.S. I honestly need someone to write out the solution for me because I have tried so much to piece together several demo examples without getting the desired results. I don't really even understand how to make a click event yet. I have been reduced to an infant by this problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code you are looking for:

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
    $('.daddy .baby').removeClass('fat').addClass('skinny');
});
```

---

You claim to be using jQuery, but you are not utilizing it in your code at all.

You can rewrite your code as follows:

```
$('.baby').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('fat skinny');
});
```

There's absolutely no need for inline javascript.

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MLHDh/

Comment: /agree, take a read of "Javascript the Good Parts" (really is a pamphlet), and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript. Using javascript in this way will only lead to pain, suffering and hating on a good language.

Comment: I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help! I am digesting your example and breaking it down. I knew that this was pretty simple but I have never posted to a question board before. Thanks for pointing out that my entire approach is bad (Joseph and Louis). I needed to know that so I can stop now. Thank you!!

Comment: @Louis - "Javascript the Good Parts" will be WAYYYY over his head. He clearly needs something closer to a "Javascript for Dummies" book.

Comment: @maxedison, the google video talk is extremely basic level stuff (1hour watch), as is the book. It uses simple language and runs through examples you can follow. Its also short! Great for any beginner. Further to that point, JS for dummies is exactly the type of code we're bashing on. Best to learn it properly the first time.

Comment: @william-larsen, don't be discouraged, while I don't like the community here very much [read: too many of "gods gifts"], it sure has saved me when in a bind at times.

Comment: @Louis thank you. I got the kindle version of the "Good Parts" book. I will check out the video you mentioned too. Thanks for the encouragement. I am not going to lie—-it kinda hurt when maxedison related me to needing a "dummies" book. I have had now two great answers that worked well and I am learning so much just through the interaction here. Thanks.

Comment: Just don't forget to select josephs answer as the answer, it gives him points and shows you accept answers (leading to people bothering to answer your questions at all in the future). :) Good luck!

Comment: @William Larsen - Just so you know: To accept an answer, click on the checkmark next to it, and it'll turn green. Good luck!